# sqlite3.OperationalError in Python 3 when creating table

Tags: python, sqlite, syntax-error

The following code shows up this error when run.

#### Error:

```
 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY LadID)""".format(usr))
 sqlite3.OperationalError: near "LadID": syntax error
```

#### Code:

```
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE {}
        (LadID INTEGER,
        foreName TEXT,
        surname TEXT,
        interests INTEGER,
        gender TEXT,
        mob INTEGER
        INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (LadID))""".format(usr))
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you have omitted a comma after `mob INTEGER` also you need to change the last column to `LadID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`.

Note that you should put your column name at the start of column definition and don't need to parenthesis.

```
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE {}
        (LadID INTEGER,
        foreName TEXT,
        surname TEXT,
        interests INTEGER,
        gender TEXT,
        mob INTEGER,
        LadID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)""".format(usr))
```

Comment: But now I get this: sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

Comment: Why you have putted `LadID` within parenthesis?  in `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (LadID)`

Comment: Without the parenthesis I get sqlite3.OperationalError: near "LadID": syntax error

Comment: It can be `LadID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` anyway.

Comment: @TomHaines marcus is right you need to put the column name on first `LadID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`